# encode_json with PHP and foreach issue

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have some PHP code to pull database entries, and put them into a multi-dimensional array. I need this exact format, and I cannot figure out how to loop with foreach.

```
        $res    = $GLOBALS["Database"]->result("SELECT * FROM test");

    $json = array
    (
        "data" => array
        (
            "entry" => array
            (
                array
                        (
                "player"    => $res["id"],
                "reason"    => $res["reason"],
                "postedTimestamp" => $res["posted"],
                "postedLong" => $postedLong
             )
            )
         )
    );
```

I cannot figure out where to put the foreach, I want it to loop through and pull all entries and create a new 'entry' for each entry in the DB it finds.

Comment: In PHP, array keys need to be unique, so you can't have two or more by the name of `entry`. Why not have `{"data": [ [..], [..], .. ]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not:

```
$data = array("data"=>array("entry"=>array()));
foreach($res as $r){
    $data['data']['entry'][] = array(
            "player"    => $res["id"],
            "reason"    => $res["reason"],
            "postedTimestamp" => $res["posted"],
            "postedLong" => $postedLong
         );
}
```

This should work :)

Doing like this, yout "entry" array will have numeric keys, then you can have many structures inside it. Got it?

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loop given in that code please use this to manage your array.

```
<?php
//$json = array
//    (
//        "data" => array
//        (
//            "entry" => array
//            (
//                array
//                        (
//                "player"    => $res["id"],
//                "reason"    => $res["reason"],
//                "postedTimestamp" => $res["posted"],
//                "postedLong" => $postedLong
//             )
//            )
//         )
//    );
$r    = $GLOBALS["Database"]->result("SELECT * FROM test");
foreach($r as $res)
{
    $data['data']['entry'][] = array
              (
                "player"    => $res["id"],
                "reason"    => $res["reason"],
                "postedTimestamp" => $res["posted"],
                "postedLong" => $postedLong
             );

}

?>
```